# the old dialog opens with the new dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Hi
I am using jquery dialog box,and when I am selecting a record from atable, it call the dialog box, then when I close it and chose another record, it opens the old dialog with the new dialog... what is the problem

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnenterpat").click(function () {
        $("#enter_payment").dialog('open');
    });
    $("#enter_payment").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            ok: function () {
                retur_dialog = 'ok';
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
        },
        beforeClose: function () {
            if (retur_dialog == 'ok') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ssssssss.php',
                    data: {
                        pm1: $("#pm1").val(),
                        pm2: $("#pm2").val(),
                        pm3: $("#pm3").val(),
                        pm4: $("#pm4").val(),
                        pm5: $("#pm5").val(),
                        pm6: $("#pm6").val(),
                        pm7: $("#pm7").val(),
                    },

                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

First page:

```
<?php
    include ("angela_test.php")
?>
<div style="font-size:12px;">
</div>
<br />
<table id="tbl_angela_test_data"></table>
<div id="p_angela_test_data"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selected_id;
    var colCap = Array();
    var colDef = Array();
    var grp_filter = 0;

      $.ajax({
         url: "getColDefs.php" ,
         data: {table: "bk_accounts", userid: "5", groupid: "1"},
         dataType: "json",
         async: false,
         success: function (data) {
                colCap = data[0];
                colDef = data[1];
         }
      });

    var cols = '';
    for(i=0; i<colDef.length; i++) {
        cols += colDef[i].name;
        if (i != (colDef.length-1)) {
            cols += ';';
        }
    }

    jQuery("#tbl_angela_test_data").jqGrid({
        url:'admin/angela_test_table_get.php',  
        postData: {columns: cols},
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10,20,30],
        colNames: colCap,
        colModel: colDef,
        pager: "#p_angela_test_data",
        viewrecords: true,
        toolbar: [true, 'both'],
        caption: "angela_test",
        onSelectRow: function(id){
            selected_id = id;
            $("#angela_test_del_bnt, #angela_test_edit_bnt").attr("disabled", false);
            }
    });
    jQuery("#tbl_angela_test_data").setGridWidth(500);

    $("#t_tbl_angela_test_data").height(40);
    $("#t_tbl_angela_test_data").append('<button id="angela_test_edit_bnt" style="height:30px; width:100px;" disabled="true">Edit</button>');


    // edit button
    $("#angela_test_edit_bnt").click(function(){
        var rw = '#angela_test_item_'+selected_id;
        var maintab = $("#tabs");
        if ($(rw).html() != null) {
            maintab.tabs('select',rw);
        } else {
            maintab.tabs('add',rw,'Edit form');
           $(rw, '#tabs').load('admin/angelatest.php?id='+selected_id);
        }
    });


//////////////////////////////
})
</script>
```

and the second page is:

```
<?php
 include_once("angela_test.php"); 
?>
<input type="button" id="btnenterpat" value="Enter Payment">
```

and the dialog code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnenterpat").click(function () {
        $("#angela_test").dialog('open');
    });

    $("#angela_test").dialog({

        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
        },
    }).parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
});
</script>

<!--Enter Payment windows --> 
<div id="angela_test" ></div>
<!--dialog windows end -->
```

Comment: "it opens the old dialog with the new dialog", what do you mean?

Comment: Hi .. ok it's like this, let say that I have 3 pages, the first page have a table the second one have a botton to the therd page that will show the dialog contain a form... when I am chosing a record from the first page and press edit, I go to the second page that have another botton, I press this botton, it show me the dialog, then I close it , and close the second page, then again from the first page chose another record and continue it show me the old dialog for the first chose with the new dialog and the number gos up with dialogs.

Comment: So, you've got a dialog that calls another dialog? Why don't you do a simplified versino of your pages on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com? This will clarify your question vastly, enabling us to help.

Comment: the website is too big I can't put just the problem cause it will not work.. but when I am not using the second page wich contain the botton to the dialog , its working perfect, like there is somthing wrong with the second page, I want to know how to reset the pages when I am closing tha dialog?????

Comment: my problem is similar to problem (jquery ui dialog close doesn't clear dialog)

Comment: So you created a dialog for each row in the table as well?

Comment: It seems that you uses jQuery UI Tabs to show the 2nd page, not dialog... Is this your revised solution??

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$('#some-div').dialog('destroy')` would restore the `#some-div` element to its original form before calling `$('#some-div').dialog(...)`. Maybe you can consider doing that upon closing the dialog?

Comment: yes, I am using tab to open the secon page. so how can I refresh the tab cause it will solve thr problem??

Comment: If you load the tab via AJAX, you just need to make sure the option `cache: false` is set, so every time this tab is selected, it would load the content via AJAX each time.

Comment: ok.. when I am using remove dialog and chose another record, it's work perfect , but the botton for the dialog just works for one time, how I can reload the dialog???